# How do I sort a string of numbers in polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

I would like to sort researve_tb by hote_id number.

```
researve_tb.groupby(['hotel_id'])\
          .agg([
              pl.var("total_price").alias("price_var"),
              pl.std("total_price").alias("price_std"),
          ])\
          .fill_null(0)\
          .sort(by = 'hotel_id')
```

```
shape: (300, 3)
hotel_id    price_var   price_std
str f64 f64
"h_1"   3.1865e9    56449.526127
"h_10"  8.2581e8    28736.968061
"h_100" 3.1983e8    17883.835689
"h_101" 2.4024e9    49014.703676
"h_102" 3.5769e8    18912.755159
"h_103" 3.5459e9    59547.090609
"h_104" 1.1689e10   108114.689945
"h_105" 4.1628e8    20402.866279
"h_106" 3.2172e9    56719.925952
"h_107" 2.8339e9    53234.82114
"h_108" 1.2080e9    34756.486205
"h_109" 8.8868e8    29810.766816
... ... ...
"h_89"  7.8036e8    27934.869305
"h_9"   1.2244e10   110651.843841
"h_90"  1.0169e9    31889.51515
"h_91"  2.8277e10   168159.015653
"h_92"  1.0224e10   101113.215521
"h_93"  1.4129e9    37587.964977
"h_94"  3.1292e9    55939.692867
"h_95"  3.3138e10   182037.696857
"h_96"  3.1592e8    17774.225072
"h_97"  5.4747e9    73991.116584
"h_98"  3.4329e9    58590.896578
"h_99"  5.7454e9    75798.599541
```

Now, I got this result in this code.

I would like to get a result below.
shape: (300, 3)

hotel_id

"h_1"

"h_2"

"h_3"
.
.
.

How do I change this code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the hotel_id column is of type string, so the sorting is based on alphabetical ordering rather than numerical ordering.

You can try the below:

```
# example dataframe

researve_tb = pl.DataFrame({
    'hotel_id': ['h_1','h_1', 'h_2','h_2','h_10','h_10'],
    'total_price': [1,2,3,4,5,6]
})

# transformation
researve_tb.groupby(pl.col('hotel_id').str.slice(2).cast(pl.UInt16))\
          .agg([
              pl.var("total_price").alias("price_var"),
              pl.std("total_price").alias("price_std"),
          ])\
          .fill_null(0)\
          .sort(by = 'hotel_id')

# Result

shape: (3, 3)
┌──────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ hotel_id ┆ price_var ┆ price_std │
│ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ u16      ┆ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1        ┆ 0.5       ┆ 0.707107  │
│ 2        ┆ 0.5       ┆ 0.707107  │
│ 10       ┆ 0.5       ┆ 0.707107  │
└──────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

Here I casted the hotel_id column to integer before the sorting

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it always starts with `h_` then you can just do

```
.sort(pl.col('hotel_id').str.extract("(\d+)").cast(pl.Int32()))
```

If it doesn't always start with `h_` then you'd need to extract the letter before the underscore to sort by that then do a secondary sort on the numeric.

```
.sort([pl.col('hotel_id').str.extract("(\D+)_"),
       pl.col('hotel_id').str.extract("(\d+)").cast(pl.Int32())])
```

In both cases you're just using regex to extract the part of `hotel_id` that you want to sort by with the numeric component being cast to a numeric type so that 2 comes before 10.

You can avoid regex if you employ a helper column

```
.with_columns(pl.col('hotel_id').str.split("_").alias('asplit')) \
    .sort([pl.col('asplit').arr.first(), pl.col('asplit').arr.last().cast(pl.Int32())]) \
    .select(pl.exclude('asplit'))
```